# Travis CI fails to access MySQL RDS instance in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, travis-ci, amazon-rds

I'm trying to do Testing of my APIs and had it as a part of CI process for which I'm using Travis. Extra info: Used SQL Alchemy to query db within the API implementation.

The testing is done using a dedicated Docker container environment (using docker-compose for testing) within the Travis. But when it comes to the point when RDS instance in my AWS should be accessed, I'm getting the below error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003,
>   "Can't connect to MySQL server on (timed out)")

For reference below is my travis.yml file

```
language: python
python: 3.6
services:
  - docker
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: Tests
      script:
      - echo "Perform the testing"
      - docker-compose -f tests/docker-compose.yml up --build
```

The same tests when run locally goes through without any problem. Not sure if it's something to do with IP addresses of travis instance. However, I'm mentioning my AWS access key and secret key in the settings of Travis.

Any hints or suggestion to solve up this problem is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I dont mean to get fussy about semantics, but this sounds like an integration test and not a unit test. If your goal / requirement is unit testing then you should be totally abstracting away the database.

Comment: However, if thats how you wanna do it, check the credentials on your connection string. Sounds like the Docker container cant access your database, but your local build can

Comment: You should check the security group for your RDS instance to see what IP ranges are allowed. AWS access key and secret key don't have anything to do with RDS connection. Also, can your container connect to the internet at all?

Comment: @SergeyKovalev yes I have a security group which allows only specific CIDR (only developers in our team). I was wondering how can I mention IP addresses range of Travis. Because IP address for travis is not static and each time Travis is triggered, a new different IP address is allocated. Travis blog mentions a range of limited IP addresses but it seems like it is not the only IP addresses travis can take. I checked even IP addresses not mentioned in Travis blog are also been taken by travis machine for my builds

Comment: It's not a good idea to run your test cases against AWS RDS due to the potential security issues  (you'll have to commit RDS credentials). Instead you can use databases as mentioned here https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/

Answer (score 0):

Is there a compelling reason to not use the `mysql` service provided by Travis CI? This would allow your unit tests to run against an actual test database that will be thrown away after, which is probably what you want.

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#MySQL